# Registry key file is not found for Android SDK Tools in VS2017 15.8 Preview 1.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-tools, registrykey, project-template

In Previous Visual Studio stable versions, registry key file for **Android SDK Tools** were shipped under the following location.

**Location:** Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Android SDK Tools

[image]

But in **VS2017 Preview 15.8 Preview 1.1** version, the registry key file for Android SDK Tools are shipped under the following registry location.

**Location:** Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1037082847-2228697409-3588943661-1001\Software\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_66dd38\Android

[image]

Is this an issue or will you consider this as behavior in upcoming stable version?

Awaiting for your valuable response!!!

Regards,

Saravana Pandian M.